# Twig links to current route but changing locale

Tags: symfony, url, path, twig, locale

I would add some links to differents locales versions in my existing website. It works quite well but it is pretty ugly^^

```
<li>
    <a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge(app.request.query.all|merge({_locale: 'es'}))) }}">
       <img src="{{ asset('img/flags/es.jpg') }}" alt="es">
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge(app.request.query.all|merge({_locale: 'fr'}))) }}">
       <img src="{{ asset('img/flags/fr.jpg') }}" alt="fr">
    </a>
</li>
```

Do you have an idea for doing it better ?

Comment: Nobody visiting the website will see that, don't worry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may need this in many pages and/or more than one project. Here's a possible way based on what I've been using in some:

```yml
# app/config/config.yml

# ...
parameters:
    # ...
    app_locales: [en, es, fr]

twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        locales: %app_locales%
        # ...
```

Then a template for holding flags:

```twig
{# app/Resources/views/includes/_flags.html.twig #}

{% set route = app.request.attributes.get('_route') %}
{% set route_params = app.request.attributes.get('_route_params') %}
{% set params = route_params|merge(app.request.query.all) %}

{# You may want to not print a flag/link for current view, the "if" here let you handle it #}

{% for locale in locales if locale != app.request.locale %}

    <li>
        <a href="{{ path(route, params|merge({ _locale: locale })) }}">
            <img src="{{ asset('img/flags/' ~ locale ~ '.jpg') }}" alt="{{ locale }}">
        </a>
    </li>

{% endfor %}
```

Finally include flags in any view:

```
{# app/Resources/views/base.html.twig #}

{% include 'includes/_flags.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with Silex? I don't have a config.yml file...here is my question (with 50 bounty): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49055253/silex-allow-user-to-change-langage-by-clicking-on-html-element-and-keeping-cle

Comment: For a Symfony 4 approach, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51597719/manually-switch-locale-in-symfony-4/